# What is the format modifier for 10 spaces iterating through a list to output to a table?

Tags: python, list, formatting

If I have a list of a bunch of numbers or words what format modifier do I use to output it in a table with one space and ten numbers/words per row?

```
list = [30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390,
420, 450, 480, 510, 540, 570, 600]

output table:
30 60 90 120 150 180 210 240 270 300
330 360 390 420 450 480 510 540 570 600
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use `list` as a variable name you're overriding a python function. Try the following:

```
list1 = [30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390, 420, 450, 480, 510, 540, 570, 600]

result = ''
for i in range(0, len(list1), 10):
    result += ''.join(' '.join([str(x) for x in list1[i:i+10]])) + '\n'
print(result)
```

Comment: My bad it was just for the question on here. My actual variable name was output_list

Comment: @funjunkstorage ok then!

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to specify the numbers per row

```
def create_rows(lst, numbers_per_row):
  return [lst[i:i+numbers_per_row] for i in range(0, len(lst), numbers_per_row)]

lst = [30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390,
420, 450, 480, 510, 540, 570, 600]

for row in create_rows(lst, 10):
  print(*row)
```

Output

```
30 60 90 120 150 180 210 240 270 300
330 360 390 420 450 480 510 540 570 600
```

Comment: @funjunkstorage--glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby` and `enumerate()` to make groups of 10 elements:

```
>>> l = [30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390, 420, 450, 480, 510, 540, 570, 600]

>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(item[1]) for item in group[1]) \
        for group in groupby(enumerate(l), lambda x: x[0]//10)))

30 60 90 120 150 180 210 240 270 300
330 360 390 420 450 480 510 540 570 600
```